# Place a recyclerview between 2 views

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to achieve this layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout> <!-- Always attached to the top of the parent -->
    <RecyclerView>
    <LinearLayout> <!-- Always attached to the bottom of the parent -->   
    <GridView>
<RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the  full code which have recycler view between two linear layout inside Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"/>    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_pager"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
        <View android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_pager"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
       <View android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orLoginWithEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Shop By Category"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"></GridView>    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to place recycler view between two Linear Layout inside parent Relative Layout but it is not showing the recycler view.I think it is overlapping by some view or may be any other problem.My Current layout output is

[image]

Comment: you want Linear -> recylerView -> LinearLayout from top to bottom in this order right ?

Comment: Do you require Recyclerview and GridView to scroll inside themselves or you want to scroll all items of recyclerview then show "Shop by Category" and then start GridView?

Answer (score 1):

Add this Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/listView">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orLoginWithEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Shop By Category"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout1"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `ConstraintLayout` which is more efficient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linear_2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear_1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/grid_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And add `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'` to your gradle file.

It looks like this
[image]

black -> LinearLayout

blue -> RecyclerView

green -> GridView

Answer (score 0):

### Use align attributes

To place a childLayout at the top in RelativeLayout use `alignParentTop = "true"`
To place a childLayout at the bottom in RelativeLayout use `alignParentBottom = "true"`
In your case give above attributes in your child LinearLayouts respectively . And to make sure RecyclerView lays below the First LinearLayout Use this attribute in your RecyclerView `android:layout_below = "@id/LinearLayout"`

Answer (score 0):

Use only RecyclerView and use below code :

```
recyclerView .setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 8);
recyclerView .setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

// 8 is number of column which you want to display